# JavaScript AdRotator?

Tags: javascript, xml, ads, adrotator

Does anyone know of a javascript ad rotator that behaves similar to the .NET AdRotator? Some features I am looking for are...

```
JavaScript Powered.
Stand Alone Javascript.    
Ability to pull from XML source.
Ability to work on internal and external site.
Ability to work in HTTP and HTTPS.
Ability to set regions.
Ability to set random on page load.
Ability to set auto rotate after given period.
Ability to set target="" location.
Ability to insert an html chunk vs just a linked image.
Ability to set weight.
Ability to make me toast and eggs.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be hard to find something exactly with all these requirements. But Did you try these ?

http://dongavipul.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-adrotator-like-aspnet-adrotator.html

http://unknownerror.net/2011-04/adrotator-jquery-make-rotation-picture-reproduced-679

---

**https://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/rotate-ads-in-javascript-with-ad-rotator/ (Update: 2021)**

Comment: The first one is close.  But I need something that is standalone and not dependent on a library.  Being able to load more than just a linked image would be high on my priority list too.

Comment: when you say "not dependent on a library" do you mean JQuery ?

Comment: Yes. The script could end up on external sites where I don't have control over the js library used.  I'd like to find a script that is self contained.

Comment: What u mean by ending up on external sites ?! You can download .js files and put on your own server . Modify them as you need !

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm looking to do something similar to the way Google Adsense works. I'll be serving up a series of internal banners on my site that is composed of both .NET and classic .asp pages and I'd also like to be able to do an affiliate setup where others could add the javascript snippet to their sites.  They could already have jquery installed or not.  They could also be using some other library.  I just want to minimize the chance for conflicts by keeping the code self contained.